# Equal height and width of each table cell regardless of content

Tags: html, css

I have an html table that I set the width and height to a given size. I'd like all cells in the table to be the same height and width filling up the table regardless of what's in them(even if empty) and how many cells there are.
I'd like a purely CSS solution(no JS) to this problem if possible.

In case anyone is wondering, I'm using JS to change how many cells there are in the table and I'd like the table to be same size no matter the cell count.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to write some code and if you get stuck, post the code and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: I'm just asking for help on a generic problem, I could have included code but since it's not a project specific problem and everything you could have gathered from looking at my code I already wrote down I figured it'd be pointless.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but you'd have to worry about content being clipped because it overflows to the next cell.

The important pieces are:

[table-layout: fixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)

> Table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col
> elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in
> subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

*However*

> If no widths are present on the first row, the column widths are
> divided equally across the table, regardless of content inside the
> cells.

[white-space: nowrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

> Collapses white space as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text
> wrapping) within the source.

[overflow: hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

> Content is clipped if necessary to fit the padding box. No scrollbars
> are provided, and no support for allowing the user to scroll (such as
> by dragging or using a scroll wheel) is allowed. The content can be
> scrolled programmatically (for example, by setting the value of a
> property such as offsetLeft), so the element is still a scroll
> container.

**Example:**

```css
table{
    /* Set the table width, can be a percentage or size */
    width: 100%;
    
    /* If no widths are present on the first row, the column widths are divided equally across the table */
    table-layout: fixed;
    
    /* Table border */
    border: 1px solid black;
    
    /* A margin to separate the tables */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    
    /* Set the fixed table height */
    height: 200px;
}

tr{ 
  /* Keep the cells from wrapping content to a new line. */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

td{
  /* Cell border */
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  /* Hide anything in the row that overflows the cell otherwise content could cross cell borders */
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1     ddddddddddddddddddd</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
      <td>Column 4</td>
      <td>Column 5</td>
      <td>Column 6</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1 ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</td>
      <td>Cell 5</td>
      <td>Cell 6 ggggggggggg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4 asdasdasdadsadsdasadsadsadsdas</td>
      <td>Cell 5</td>
      <td>Cell 6 jkasddsakjakjlasdjkladslkjalkjadsklajds</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
      <td>Column 4</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell 1</td>
      <td>Cell 2</td>
      <td>Cell 3</td>
      <td>Cell 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
</table>
```

Comment: When the cells have no content or all rows have content this works prefectly but when there's a difference it's no good.
https://imgur.com/a/ooippwN
Here's a picture of what exactly happens.

Comment: Like a missing cell(s)?  Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/a60mcxnk/ ?

Comment: I assume that would be a problem too but in my case it's not going to happen. What I meant is like the picture I linked, in one cell there is content and all the others are empty which messes up the sizing. In the original post this is what I meant by regardless of content, no matter what is in each cell even if empty, I'd like them to be equally sized at all times.

Comment: Pointless indeed.

Comment: Does adding a fixed height to the cells work for what you want then?  Example: https://jsfiddle.net/3409hcdb/

Comment: No because the amount of cells is changing in runtime and I'd like the table size to be constant